# MySQL Query suggestion

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a MySQL table like this -

```
ID    NAME     PARENT
=====================
1     Class    0
2     Math     1
3     Physics  1
4     Cooking  0
5     Italian  4
6     Chinese  4
```

I want a query that will give me this output -

```
ID    NAME
=====================
1     Class
2     Math Class
3     Physics Class
4     Cooking
5     Italian Cooking
6     Chinese Cooking
```

The parent's name will be appended with the child's name, like surname.

Comment: `CONCAT` will help you with that..

Comment: Use concat and CASE select statement ,,, give a shot and post the error , at least you try

Comment: @javalovers why `CASE()`?

Answer (score 2):

`LEFT JOIN` is needed on this case since there are `PARENT` that has no match on the `ID`.

```
SELECT  a.ID,
        CONCAT(a.Name, ' ', COALESCE(b.name,'')) Name
FROM    TableName a
        LEFT JOIN TableName b
            ON a.Parent = b.ID
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/81bf6/4)

you can also use `CONCAT_WS()` so that you can omit `COALESCE()`

```
SELECT  a.ID,
        CONCAT_WS(' ', a.Name, b.name) Name
FROM    TableName a
        LEFT JOIN TableName b
            ON a.Parent = b.ID
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/81bf6/7)

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT t1.ID, CONCAT(t1.NAME, ' ', t2.NAME) AS NAME
FROM your_table t1
INNER JOIN your_table t2 ON t1.PARENT = t2.ID
```